# Consuming web service in class library

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, web-config, class-library

**Scenario:** 
I am consuming a web service in my class library project and it generates a binding name and end point in `app.config`. If I reference the class library in my UI project, I also have to include the same configuration in `web.config`. My problem is I don't want to include this configuration in `web.config` because of the dependency. I want to use assembly as it own with out any dependency.

**My solution approach:** 
When I create the instance of proxy class in the class library project it shows me constructor to pass binding and endpoint.
Example

```
wsProxy proxyClass = new wsProxy(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.Endpoint endpoint)
```

I was wondering if I can pass the same binding and endpoint that I have in `app.config` so that I don't have to include either in `app.config` and `web.config`.

Comment: Hey user, I've made some modifications to your post. For future questions, try to keep these points in mind: no tags in the title, tag appropriately (it's always smart to use a language tag if it applies), stick to the point and format code. This will make your posts easier to read by others :)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will keep that in mind. This is my first post in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can create these classes without having matching configuration in the main .config file. Where you get that configuration is up to you; it could be App.config, a YML configuration file, a database, etc. As long as your code satisfies the constructor requirements for the classes you're instantiating, you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

With WCF, everything defined in your configuration file can be done programmatically.

You just need to create the objects needed to instantiate your client. Depending on the WCF features you want your application to be leveraging, you'll need classes like **EndpointAddress**, **AddressHeaderCollection**, **Uri**, **EndpointIdentity** (**DnsEndpointIdentity** or **SpnEndpointIdentity**), **Binding** (**WSHttpBinding**, **NetTcpBinding** etc.). And you might want to have these objects populated from a decoupled, centralized configuration store such as a database.